# Emmet - custom CSS snippet with user input values

Tags: json, emmet

Trying to figure out how to write a custom CSS snippet for emmet that can take custom value.
So something like what can be done with font-size fz10 = *font-size: 10px;*, looking at the [default snippet.json](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json) that snippet looks like this: `"fz": "font-size:|;"`.

I want to be able to use the trailing custom value like this: hrc10 = height: rem-calc(10px);. Tried `"hrc": "height: rem-calc(|);"` but it just replaces the whole value outputting *height: 10px;*.

The closest I've gotten is with `"hrc": "height: rem-calc(${1:?}px);"` which gives me *height: rem-calc(?px);* where the "?" is preselected. But would be really nice if the initial snippet did this.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: It’s not currently possible

Comment: Okay, thank you. "height: rem-calc(${1:?}px);" will have to do for now then.